# Flash banner won't loop in HTML modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, loops

I don't think the HTML modal is the reason for this, but my flash banner plays once it's opened, but does not loop as it is expected to. Any reason for this?

A jQuery on click event handler would work too, but can't seem to figure out how to integrate that.

Flash code:

```
    <div id="flashContent" loop="true">
        <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="300" height="250" id="14-HKS-114-300x250-LIC_HW" align="middle" loop="true">
        <param name="movie" value="14-HKS-114-300x250-LIC_HW.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
        <param name="play" value="true" />
        <param name="loop" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="window" />
        <param name="scale" value="showall" />
        <param name="menu" value="false" />
        <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
        <param name="salign" value="" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="14-HKS-114-300x250-LIC_HW.swf" width="300" height="250" loop="true">
            <param name="movie" value="14-HKS-114-300x250-LIC_HW.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="play" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="window" />
            <param name="scale" value="showall" />
            <param name="menu" value="false" />
            <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
            <param name="salign" value="" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <!--<![endif]-->
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
            </a>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
</div>
```

Comment: fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ds9fqvdn/

Comment: time to get rid of flash anyway, not cross browser compatible any more

Comment: Could you show us your flash code (ActionScript) because even the `loop` is active, if your you have a `stop()` that will never do looping ?